# convergence/divergence of a series power of n vs factorial

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> prove convergence/divergence of:
>   $$\sum\limits_{v=1}^\infty (-1)^n\cdot \frac{3^{n^2}}{(n!)^3}$$

we should first check if $$\sum\limits_{v=1}^n \frac{3^{n^2}}{(n!)^3}\rightarrow 0$$

using the ratio test

$$\frac{3^{(n+1)^2}}{((n+1)!)^3}\cdot \frac{(n!)^3}{3^{n^2}}= \frac{3^{n^2+2n+1}}{3^{n^2}}\cdot \frac{(n!)^3}{((n+1)!)^3}=\frac{3^{2n+1}}{(n+1)^3}$$

can I write now that for $n\rightarrow \infty$ $3^{2n}>n^3$ therefore
$\sum\limits_{v=1}^n \frac{3^{2n+1}}{(n+1)^3} \neq 0$?

Comment: You don't sum for the ratio test.

Comment: @Chappers edited

Answer (score 1):

As your working notes, the ratio of the $n+1$th term to the $n$th term is
$$ \frac{3^{2n+1}}{(n+1)^3}, $$
which tends to $\infty$ as $n \to \infty$, so is larger than $1$ for $n$ large enough. Therefore the terms to not decrease in absolute value, and cannot tend to zero, and the series cannot converge.

Comment: but I need to prove it? should I divide by $n^3$?

Comment: Prove what, precisely?

Comment: that $3^{2n}>n^3$

Comment: Well, I don't know: I don't know how much detail you're supposed to give. But all that sort of thing can be done by showing that $x^n e^{-x} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.